# condisi statement validated by laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9

I know this question has been asked many times before, I want to ask how unique validation can run when the status column table in the database is 0 in dilaravel 9.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'police_number' => 'required|unique:parking,police_number',
        ];
}
```

Comment: Just RTFM. Last paragraph https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique